# Reason behind “Index creation no longer defaults to five shard”

Tags: elasticsearch

What was the reasoning behind ""Index creation no longer defaults to five shard but one shard"

So far, the assumption was , more shards = more scalability = more parallelism
Isnt that change defeating the whole purpose of distributed systems like ES ?

Comment: Got some info about this "over sharding" problem - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/release-highlights-7.0.0.html . However, creating this question to hear more insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can relate to more shards= more scalability = more parallelism but this only happens when this is only useful when these shards utilize the multi-cores or more machines(data-nodes) in the cluster.

**This is the default config, which is created for the basic workloads and obviously needs more fine-tuning for the advance use cases**, which is the sole purpose of making it extensible, it's very difficult to design the perfect Elasticsearch cluster and as it depends on various factors, Elasticsearch tends to provides some default values which works more for general use-cases.

Either you start with a modest workload and then gradually your workload tends to increase, or you start with the huge workload in the begining itself(in which case, any way you will have more shards to get the benefit listed in the first line and this is for advanced use-case).

But first use is more common and the beauty of Elasticsearch is that with little knowledge you can get started and these default settings work quite well for modest workload and oftentimes you don't have to change them and even don't have to understand them in details.

Having more number of shards for a small number of documents with huge search traffic created issues(creation of 5 threads for a single search as default shards were 5) and this is the common use for most of the basic and modest applications out there.

So it makes sense to change the default shards to 1 as its more common use-case and beyond that any way you need to go deep to scale your cluster which would require fine-tuning Elasticsearch further.